# Name Of Generic "Pipe" Concept for Physical Communication?

Tags: networking, embedded

I currently have an idea rolling around in my head about how to abstract away (to some degree) common data transfer mechanisms of embedded systems such as CAN, UART, SPI, I2C, Ethernet, etc. Ideally I would want to have something like the concept of a Pipe, but that the interface doesn't really care about what physical medium/protocol the data is flowing over. If I say "transfer this data through the pipe", it just works. Obviously there would have to be some protocol specific details in the construction of this pipe object but outside of that it shouldn't matter.

Is there an industry accepted name for what I'm trying to do?

Is this concept even a good idea? I feel like it will be useful for my purposes but I don't know if it's pointless in the grand scheme of the embedded engineering world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an industry accepted name for what I'm trying to do?

Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) comes closest. Keep in mind that the mentioned buses are hardware standards that don't define higher-layer protocols. At higher levels, this might be called "sockets", though that typically refers to IP specifically.

> Is this concept even a good idea?

Probably not, unless you have specific requirements.

For example, it would be a good idea if you wish to replace an old RS-485 network with CAN but maintain the old hardware. It would then make sense to have as much of the software compatible as possible in that specific project.

Otherwise, from a general point of view, each of these buses are picked to suit quite different requirements. CAN when you need rugged & reliable, UART when you need backwards-compatibility, SPI when you need fast, synchronous, close-to-metal on-board communication, Ethernet when you need fast communication over long distances etc etc. The hardware requirements of one bus might exclude another.

For example, if I want my MCU to communicate with a "dumb" LCD, only SPI makes sense. I might have to toggle additional I/O pins together with the SPI signals. I might want to use DMA. Etc. In that context, there is no benefit for me if I have to use an abstract communication API which is portable to CAN, Ethernet etc. That's just bloat - this code will never run on any of those buses!

It makes far more sense to develop a HAL per bus type, so that you have one SPI HAL which is portable between microcontrollers. That's common and actually useful.

Comment: Those are some great points, thanks. I've indeed got a HAL for several of my peripheral drivers, for that exact reason. You've backed me down from trying to apply this concept to all the protocols :)

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are commonly used for IPC (inter process communication) or redirecting output to a file or ... For all this exists remote technologies, *'remote'* means *over the network or over an interface or bus* like RS232, SPI, ... The name for remote IPC is *remote procedure calls* (RPC), see https://os.mbed.com/cookbook/Interfacing-Using-RPC and https://github.com/EmbeddedRPC/erpc . Like with all IPC, security is a major problem, especially over a network.

I.e. writing a remote file (over TCP/IP) can be done like in https://askubuntu.com/questions/917200/how-to-redirect-command-output-from-remote-machine-to-local-file-via-ssh

The SSH login you can wrap into a function and this function to get the commands shorter (macros can also be used for wrapping a function [Wrap function call with macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690724/wrap-function-call-with-macro?noredirect=1&lq=1))

There are also various implementations of communication protocols over each other i.e. *Ethernet over USB* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB)